# Error 999999 on FeatureClass To FeatureClass conversion in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, export, features, error-999999

I am currently working on a python script where I am trying to copy selected features into a feature dataset.

Basically I have an mxd containing some layers, and for each layer I select features by their attributes, this query is based on the featuredataset name.
The script I have written get a list of the feature datasets of my geodatabase. With the name of the featuredataset, I can build a query filter (arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management) for each layers of the mxd.
If my selection return something, I export the selected feature in the proper dataset (arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion).
The script is processing the first dataset properly, but once it jumps to the next one it fails... I cannot figuring out why I am receiving the following message error(arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).)

```
#-----Work-on-the-Geodatabase-----
##path of the geodatabase 
gdb_hull="D:\\As_Con_Plans\\As_Con_Hull_part1.gdb"
##set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace=gdb_hull
##get the list of the featuredataset
fdlist =arcpy.ListDatasets()
#-----Work-on-the-mxd-----
##get the mxd path and initialise it
path_mxd="D:\\As_Con_Plans\\As_constructed.mxd"
doc_mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path_mxd)
##list of layers
fclist=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(doc_mxd)

#-----Loop-on-each-featuredataset----
for fds in fdlist:
    print "________","\n ", fds
    ##work on the featuredataset name, for suiting the query
    get_fds= fds.replace("As_con_","")
    fds_name=get_fds.replace("_","-")
    ##path of the featuredataset
    fds_path=gdb_hull+"\\"+fds
    ##prepare the query
    SQLexpression= "\"As_Constructed_Plan\"='"+fds_name+"'"
                    ##path where we will store the selection
    fds_path_test=str(fds_path)

    #-----Loop-on-each-layers-of-the-mxd-----
    for fc in fclist:
        fc_to_copy=fc.dataSource
        #fc_to_copy2=arcpy.mapping.Layer(fc_to_copy)
        ##Select the featureclasses
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (fc,"NEW_SELECTION",SQLexpression)
        ##Count the selected features
        count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))
        print fc,count
        ##if the query succeed, we will copy the  selection into the proper featuredataset
        if count>0:
            ##print some info
            fc_path2=fds_path+"\\"+str(fc)
            fc_path=str(fc_path2)
            fc_name=str(fc)
            fc_copy_from=str(fc_to_copy)

            ##check if the featureclass does not exist
            if not arcpy.Exists(fc_path):
                print "\n copying...",count," entities , on ",fc_path
                print (fc_copy_from,fds_path_test,fc_name,SQLexpression)

                arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc_to_copy,fds_path_test,fc_name,SQLexpression)
                print "export ok"
```

Comment: Are you familiar with try..except blocks? Is it possible that the next feature class has the same name as the first? You can test with arcpy.exists(fds_path_test+"\\"+fc_name) see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000004p000000. A copy of the outputs may help (turn on quick edit in the command window, select the area and right click then paste into notepad) or screen grab.

Comment: It looks like you are looping through the output feature datasets and storing the feature class more than once (once in each feature dataset) hence the error - names must be unique in the database, not just the dataset. If there is only one feature dataset in the output database *gdb_hull = "D:\\As_Con_Plans\\As_Con_Hull_part1.gdb"* then I'll need to look harder. Check also for spaces and non-alphanumeric characters in the layer names, that will also cause that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured out that my problem was linked to the name of the feature class' output. It is the fc_name of the following line:

> arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc_to_copy,fds_path_test,fc_name,SQLexpression).

I have run some test and discovered that I can't add 2 similar output name... even if it is processing a different dataset... So to fix the problem, I have created an incremented index that I linked to the feature class name (*new_fc_name=fc_name+str(i)* with I incremented after a loop). It may not be the best way to process, but at least, it is working...

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 check:

1. Check if name is valid

   `vname = arcpy.ValidateTableName(fc_name,wksp)`
2. Check if name exist

   ```
   def validUniqueName(name, wk):
       """ Create a unique name not exist in GDB
       Note: you can fix limit to number of pas and add test if name is too long"""
       check = True
       while check:
           check = arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(wk, name))
           if check:
               name = "{}_1".format(name)

       return name
   ```

Add 2 lines in function:

```
vname = arcpy.ValidateTableName(fc_name,wksp)
v_unique_name = validUniqueName(vname,wksp)
```

Test

```
>>> name = u"Voirie etroite"
>>> name
u'Voirie etroite'
>>> vname = arcpy.ValidateTableName(name,wk)
>>> vname
u'Voirie_etroite'
>>> vuname = validUniqueName(vname,wk)
>>> vuname
u'Voirie_etroite_1'
```